# Bulk generate Alias Drupal - HTTP POST is Required

Tags: php, ajax, drupal, drupal-7

I'm meeting a problem with Drupal batch during "Alias bulk generation". After having deleted alias, every times I launch this action , I get a JS error in file "progress.js" :

https://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/844245errorjs.png

```
Drupal.progressBar.prototype.sendPing = function () {
  if (this.timer) {
    clearTimeout(this.timer);
  }
  if (this.uri) {
    var pb = this;
    // When doing a post request, you need non-null data. Otherwise a
    // HTTP 411 or HTTP 406 (with Apache mod_security) error may result.
    $.ajax({
      type: this.method,
      url: this.uri,
      data: '',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function (progress) {
        // Display errors.
        if (progress.status == 0) {
          pb.displayError(progress.data);
          return;
        }
        // Update display.
        pb.setProgress(progress.percentage, progress.message);
        // Schedule next timer.
        pb.timer = setTimeout(function () { pb.sendPing(); }, pb.delay);
      },
      error: function (xmlhttp) {
        pb.displayError(Drupal.ajaxError(xmlhttp, pb.uri));
      }
    });
  }
};
```

The cause of this JS error is linked to the batch.inc :

```
function _batch_do() {
  // HTTP POST required.
  file_put_contents("/var/www/docroot/tmp/requestType", $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'], FILE_APPEND);
  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST') {
    drupal_set_message(t('HTTP POST is required.'), 'error');
    drupal_set_title(t('Error'));
    return '';
  }

  // Perform actual processing.
  list($percentage, $message) = _batch_process();
  file_put_contents("/var/www/docroot/tmp/requestType", array('status' => TRUE, 'percentage' => $percentage, 'message' => $message), FILE_APPEND);
  drupal_json_output(array('status' => TRUE, 'percentage' => $percentage, 'message' => $message));
}
```

Indeed, $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] is equal to "GET" instead of "POST", and this results in PHP error. Nevertheless, it's really a POST request which is sent, but Drupal "sees" a GET request.

Consequently, the bulk generate is blocked.

Any idea ?

If you need more information, don't hesitate.

My version Drupal  : 7.55

Comment: "Nevertheless, it's really a POST request which is sent, but Drupal "sees" a GET request." I highly doubt this, it sounds very unlikely that PHP would somehow not know what HTTP method was used to generate the request. Have you verified this in your browser's network tab? And what is the value of `this.method` in your JS? Is your JS even running and making the ajax call (e.g. you're not getting a full postback instead, for instance)?

Comment: try to clear caches before bulk generation

Comment: @ADyson Yes, when I debug, POST is well in "this.method". It's JS which is running and making the ajax call. Two parameters are sending and "seeing" by PHP.

Comment: @Fky, Yes It works ! But why ? I don't understand?

Comment: @Ranpie49 a lot of information are in cache about node , terms etc.. so aliases need to clear cache before to update / create on bulk operation